# Why this exec command only works in zshrc but not in profile?

Tags: linux, ssh, zsh, profile

This question is going to be so simple but I need to know how this just works in on side but in other place don't, to end ssh sesion when tmux closes I used the answer proposed in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17465215

I placed similar code inside my /etc/zsh/zprofile and it works, but if I put the same code in /etc/profile the tmux session ends immediately after ssh login, what is happening?

PS: The code in question is this:

```
if [[ -z $TMUX && -n $SSH_TTY ]]; then
     exec tmux -2 new-session -s $TTY
fi
```

Comment: there's two approaches in the answer you link to. Which one do you actually mean? To save the confusion, I'd recommend you actually put the code that works in one place, but not the other, into your question here. :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I've updated the post

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (my comment before I edited this  here was put under the wrong post, sorrry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax isn't valid shell.  `&&` connects two different and independent shell commands, and it can't be used in a `test`, `[` or `[[` command.  Some versions of test provide `-a` and `-o` for *and* and *or*, and some do not.

In addition, `/etc/profile` (and the `.d` directory, if your distro has it) must be able to be run by any POSIX shell.  Thus, `[[`, which is not found in POSIX, is not acceptable in `/etc/profile` and can break things.

If you want to write this in a POSIX-compatible way for `/etc/profile`, you can write this:

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ] && [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
     exec tmux -2 new-session -s "$TTY"
fi
```